# SSRS fills in arbitrary value when no result is returned in query

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with column and row groups to calculate inventory.
there are some items in a column group that do not have any results in the query.

for example, item 009000 does not have any inventory entries in FY2016, I checked the query and indeed, there is nothing in it for that item in FY2016.

the report fills something in however and fills in the same value for every empty result. Even more confusing, this arbitrary value changes if I refresh the report. I want this field empty, I've used IsNothing and <> '' and <> 0 but to no avail, it always fills something in (second screenshot). I'm so confused. I have no idea what could be causing it, there is no calculation in the field. (first screenshot)

[image: Design View]

[image: Arbitrary values]

Comment: Are you running the report in BIDS or in the report server?

Comment: I get it on the report server. The report is too resource heavy for BIDS on my machine.

Comment: Can you post your expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Change expression for example, if you have numeric field then use expression `=Sum(Inventory.value)` instead of `=Inventory.value`
s

Comment: Hi Manoj,

this was the problem. I still don't understand why i can't just set the numeric field. I used First() as i didn't want it to sum.

Comment: if you set First() instead of Sum(),then it will show you the first value for the group in dataset.